# selectedIndex is undefined javascript

Tags: javascript

My select is giving me undefined for is index.

My code:

HTML

```
<div name="daysToReorder" class="days_to_reorder" onchange="getReOrderTables(this)"> Day to reorder <br>
              <select name="daysToReorder">
              <option value="A">A</option>
              <option value="B">B</option>
              <option value="C">C</option>
              <option value="D">D</option>
              <option value="E">E</option>
              <option value="F">F</option>
              </select></div>
```

JS

```
  function getReOrderTables(select)
    {

    alert(select.selectedIndex);


    }
```

Comment: `this` is the `<div/>`, not the `<select/>`(div's doesn't have a `selectedIndex`-property)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `onchange` is on the `<div>`, `this` refers to the `<div>`. `<div>`s don't have a `selectedIndex`.

Try applying the event to the `<select>` instead.